# Gerrit Get Content REST API returns 404 (Not Found)

Tags: git, rest, gerrit

I am trying to fetch the content of a file using the below Gerrrit REST API.

Get Content

> 'GET
> /projects/{project-name}/branches/{branch-id}/files/{file-id}/content'

Gets the content of a file from the HEAD revision of a certain branch.

Always  it returns **404 not found**,

Anybody has tried this , help me.

or any other way to download latest file from gerrit project through REST API.
Requirement is file needs to be downloaded given a project name & Branch.

Comment: The endpoint worked pretty well for me... could you post the real command you're executing?

Comment: Sorry I can't share exact url (private project) but what I am using is similar like below.

gerritprojecturl/a/projects/project_name/branches/refs%2Fheads%2Fbranchname/files/subfolder1%2Ffilename.js/content

thanks.

Comment: Do you use `pygerrit2` or `curl`? With `curl`, it's like `curl --digest --user <user>:<httpassword> <url>/a/<api>` for a GET request.

Comment: I am using python request library for REST APIs calls. It works well for other requests rather than get content.

Comment: @BipinBopaliya Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In my case, I was trying on Gerrit's older version which was not supporting this endpoint. With higher gerrit version this API endpoint working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the "refs/heads/" prefix to the branch name.

Change:

```
gerritprojecturl/a/projects/project_name/branches/refs%2Fhea‌​ds%2Fbranchname/file‌​s/subfolder1%2Ffilen‌​ame.js/content
```

To:

```
gerritprojecturl/a/projects/project_name/branches/branchname/file‌​s/subfolder1%2Ffilen‌​ame.js/content
```

Comment: I have tried without  "refs/heads/", that is also not working.

Comment: Have you tried with success another simpler endpoint to validate the process? Ex: gerritprojecturl/a/projects/?d to get all Gerrit projects. Have the projectname, branchname or subfolder some character which need to be escaped?

Comment: Yes, I have tried upto gerritprojecturl/a/projects/project_name/branches/branchname and it gives all the branches but when I adds files it gives 404.

Comment: So something is wrong with "subfolder1%2Ffilename.js"... could you post the real value?